# Creating a file in Python. Beginner. How to format text in the created file

Tags: python

first post here...I'm learning about Python and I was able to learn how to create a .txt file from Python. However, in the tutorial I follow, once I run the code I am supposed to see these 4 lines in the .txt file

Hello World
This is our new text file
and this is another line.
Why? Because we can.

However what I see once I create the file is this:

Hello WorldThis is our new text fileand this is another line.Why? Because we can.

Basically instead of 4 different lines I see everything together in the same line. My question is, how can I make sure I am getting 4 lines and not everything together. Thank you, this is my code:

```
file = open("C:/Users/efacg/Desktop/OPENME/testfile.txt","w") 

file.write("Hello World") 
file.write("This is our new text file") 
file.write("and this is another line.") 
file.write("Why? Because we can.") 

file.close()
```

Comment: "Hello World\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Python!

You would need to tell python you want to end the line by adding '\n' to each of your write statements:

```
file = open("C:/Users/efacg/Desktop/OPENME/testfile.txt","w") 

file.write("Hello World\n") 
file.write("This is our new text file\n") 
file.write("and this is another line.\n") 
file.write("Why? Because we can.\n") 

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print()` in Python 3:

```
f = open('Hello.txt', 'w')
print('Hello World', file=f)
print('This is our new text file', file=f)
```

The following works for both Python 2 and 3.

```
f = open('Hello.txt', 'w')
f.write("Hello World\n")
f.write("This is our new text file\n") 
f.close()
```

`\n` will be converted to `os.linesep` automatically by Python.

Comment: it says that my reputation doesnt allow me to give a vote ;/

Answer (score 0):

Use "\n" in between your text, from where you want to start a new line. Just like below in the example :

Code :

```
f = open("Hello.txt","w")
f.write("This is first line.\nThis is second line.")

f = open("Hello.txt","r")
print(f.read())
```

Output :

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
```

Comment: Thank you very much